# Bootstrap site title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website using bootstratp including fontawesome plugin.  I would like to add a title to my site like few letters bold and few lettters small and italic ect. Just to give you an idea, i have attached an image of a site I found as a sample. Unfortunately I was not able to view source of that site to see how they implimented. Could someone give me some idea how to build this ?

Sorry  Idon't have any code to share at this point.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by title you mean the "THINSLICES:serious apps, Fun people" bit at the top, I would imagine from looking at it that it is an image. You could make an image with something (Visio or Paint) and then just include the image in the navication bar using an image tag. Im sure there are plenty of free tools to make images like the one you've shown here (but I don't know any hence why I said the only two pieces of software I could think of)

Seeing as you have twitter bootstrap as a tag this is something along the lines of the html that would be used (Havn't tested it so may not be 100% correct)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><image src="MyImage.png"></image></li>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are correct.It is an image. Is this someting we can do with fotnawesome? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I've never used it. Doesn't really matter what you use to make the image as long as the image looks the way you want it to.